# Infinite loops - throw a timeout error if execution exceeds certain time - how to return to control flow

Tags: javascript

For the following code the idea is that we have guards to throw a timeout error if any loops cause the execution to take longer than a specified amount of time.

```
function test() {

var ___timeout___ = Date.now();

while (true) {
    if (Date.now() > ___timeout___ + 1000) {
        throw new Error('Timed out');
    }
    console.log('Infinite Loop?');
}

}

test();
console.log('left loop 1');
test();
console.log('left loop 2');
```

However when I call the infinite loops with the function `test()` and some `console.log` statements to show we have successfully called the loop, exited the loop without crashing the browser, called another loop and finally left the second loop.

Why am I not getting the expected output? What exactly is the point of stopping the execution if we can't continue with our program? Unless we are simply building this in as a precaution for each loop

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? I'm pretty sure `throw new Error()...` will stop JS execution

Comment: "The throw statement throws a user-defined exception. Execution of the current function will stop (the statements after throw won't be executed)" - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

Comment: So what's the point would you just build this statement into every loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can surround it with `try catch` so the exception does not break the program execution.

```js
function test() {

  var ___timeout___ = Date.now();

  while (true) {
    if (Date.now() > ___timeout___ + 1000) {
        throw new Error('Timed out');
    }
  }
}

try {
  test();
} catch(e) {
  console.log('left loop 1');
}
try {
  test();
} catch(e){
  console.log('left loop 2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this the solution you are looking for .

```
async function test() {

var ___timeout___ = Date.now();

while (true) {
    if (Date.now() > ___timeout___ + 1000) {
    return false;        
//throw new Error('Timed out');
    }
    console.log('Infinite Loop?');
}

}

await test();
console.log('left loop 1');
await test();
console.log('left loop 2');
```